# Do Azure Easy Tables support relationships?

Tags: api, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm just learning about `Azure Mobile Apps`. Do `Easy Tables` support relationships? My existing schema has multiple tables with foreign key constraints, and I need the ability to create complex joins (`Easy APIs`). I'm trying to understand the point of all this "Easy" stuff.

Should I skip it and just create a custom `ApiController` and manual db script deployment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy Tables are just simple SQL Azure tables that are exposed through a Web API OData Service endpoint. So when you create them you can connect to the SQL Azure and create your relationships etc there and customize the API code to include those relational data in the response.

From my experience they are good if you dont have complicated logic/business rules or complicated queries.

To my experience if you have complicated stuff even normal Web API OData Service endpoints would not help because the interception of the requests makes the code complicated and you are better off creating your own Web APIs.

I almost feel like the Easy API and Easy Tables are more designed to give you a kick start for a simple mobile app in a hackathon or to put an idea together as a demo real quick. But for real life enterprise stuff I will go with building my own Web API.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was thinking. Should I stick with App Service or just host my Web APIs in a cloud service? I'm not sure if I should stick with the abstraction layer Microsoft has built.

Comment: @Mark13426 You can host your Web API as a Web APP with App type of App Service, or you can use an API App. the abstractions are mostly for fast starts, but with a simple Web API hosted as a Web App you can add all the features as you need them.